# segmentation of an arabic word to characters python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I want to segment handwritten Arabic words into characters from a picture. I've already segmented the word to subword using python. Now I want to segment the subwords to characters and I don't know how to do it. Can you please help me with that.

[image: original word]

[image: segmented word to subwords]